# Errors using PCL's savePCDFile in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to run the following PCL example :

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

using namespace pcl;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
PointCloud<PointXYZ> cloud;

cloud.width = 50;
cloud.height = 1;
cloud.is_dense = false;
cloud.points.resize(50);

for (int i = 0; i < cloud.points.size(); i++) {
    cloud.points[i].x = 1024 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    cloud.points[i].y = 1024 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    cloud.points[i].z= 1024 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
}

pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII("testing", cloud);
}
```

It seems the problem is caused by the "savePCDFile" function. Here are the errors:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Btw, I installed pcl using vcpkg.

Comment: Did you create a project manually or did CMake create it for you? Chances are you are not linking against the PCL library files

Comment: I installed PCL x64 and it works fine now. Even when I set VS to x86. Does it make sense?

Comment: It might, depending on your project settings! Please do not forget to upvote if you found this useful :-)